# Couchdb, couch-connector and multiple databases

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, couchdb, couchapp

I'm wondering if anyone has tried the get `couch-connector` to work with multiple databases.

I have `couchapp` which uses multiple databases and I'm having trouble with `couch-connector` to work with it. Couch-connector works great when I'm using one database, but if I try to `fetch` a collection from another database view I have problem, because it uses my main design document in url.

One more question: what's the best practice for implementing a chat app in my project. Is it better to have one database as inbox or should I make databases for every user. Im concered for scallability of app in case of one inbox database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[couch_connector](https://github.com/janmonschke/backbone-couchdb) isn't really built to do more than a single database. You might checkout [backbone.couchdb.js](https://github.com/pyronicide/backbone.couchdb.js) if you're not too far along in your project. It supports multiple databases via code like:

```
var main_db = Backbone.couch.db('main');
var other_db = Backbone.couch.db('other');
```

You can see some sample code (albeit with a single DB) in the [readme-backbone.js app](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/readme-backbone.js/blob/master/_attachments/js/app.js) I'm building at Couchbase.

Hopefully the two libraries are similar enough that porting your code won't be hard.

**For your inbox question:**
The first concern is actually your MapReduce Views--they only deal with the documents in a single database. If you'll be using a View to access data based on channels, dates, users, etc, then you'll need all the documents within a single database. However, you could split the database on something "bigger" than per-user (like per-channel).

Hope that helps.